# Sequelize - Node Js - enum and Integer field Search option

Tags: javascript, node.js, enums, sequelize.js, typecasting-operator

In Sequelize - ORM Node JS

when using the `enum` and `integer` field while searching particular element with `like` operator gives error as:

> ```
> No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

How did i need to type cast for `integer` and `enum` field ?

My where Condition in query  `job.status` is a `enum` field

```js
whereCondn = { 
        $or:[
        {
            '$job.jobReferenceId$': {
                $iLike: (search ? search: '')
            }
        },
        {
            '$job.jobTitle$': {
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job.experienceLevel$': {
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job.location$': {
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job.status$': {
                $like:   '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job->hospital.name$':{
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job->grade.gradeName$':{
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job->speciality.specialityName$':{
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        },
        {
            '$job->specialityService.serviceName$':{
                $iLike: '%'+(search ? search: '')+'%'
            }
        }
        ],
        $and :[
        {
            '$job.draft$' : false
        },
        {
            'doctorId' : bodyInput['doctorId']
         }
        ]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else visiting this page like me:

You can use Sequelize.literal this way -

```js
...
where: Sequelize.literal(`"job"."status"::TEXT LIKE '%${searchKeyword}%'`)),
...
```